# How to open a link inside of iframe when a user trys to open link in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying for a while to get this working before I finally decided to post it here.

So I have a navigation bar and each item in the navigation bar opens a link inside a iframe that I have on the home page.

Homepage (index.php) has all of this code

My nav bar:

```
<ul id="nav">

        <li style="width: 20%">
            <a href="home.php" target="iframe" id="navBarLeft">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li style="width: 30%">
            <a href="saleItems.php" target="iframe" >Sale Items</a>
            <ul>                    
                <li><a href="saleFlyer.php" target="iframe" id="navMid">Sale Flyer/Coupons</a></li>                 
            </ul>
        </li>               

        <li style="width: 30%">
            <a href="location.php" target="iframe">Store Information</a>
        </li>

        <li style="width: 20%">
            <a href="contact.php" id="navBarRight" target="iframe">Contact Us</a>
        </li>

</ul>
```

My iframe:

```
<iframe src="home.php" name="iframe" id = "iframeID" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

So by default it loads up home.php and user can browse through all the links in the navigation bar and that respective php file from the link will load up in the iframe.

However if a user tried to open it in a new tab, the page will look weird since they are all optimized for the iframe.

Any way so if a user does try to open a link from the nav bar in a new tab, it loads up index.php (my homepage) and inside the iframe the page that they tried to open up with new tab shows up in the iframe instead.

Comment: This is not possible

Comment: Impossible and very much **not done** - do not try to force different behaviour on the user. They already decided they want it in a new tab, don't force your iframe on them. This is entirely against what the user expects or wants. Also, `iframes`? In this day and age? They don;t work naturally on mobiles, so use them sparsely.

Answer (score 0):

You can hang on the link *onclick*, inside which will be the code of changing the iframe src.

```
<a href="saleItems.php" onclick="document.getElementById('iframeID').src = this.getAttribute('href'); return false;" >Sale Items</a>
```

Comment: this does take care of the middle clicking on the link but still doesn't take care of the option if the user right clicks the link and opens it in a new tab.